# TYPO3 - How to render felogin with typoscript at a certain spot on a page?

Tags: typo3, felogin

How can I render felogin to a certain spot on a website? Does this work with typoscript and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Render within pure TypoScript**

It depends how would you like to display it. If directly in TypoScript, you can just copy `plugin.tx_felogin_pi1` object into your content.

```
page = PAGE
page.10 < plugin.tx_felogin_pi1
page.10.storagePid = 1
```

You need to setup appropriate `storagePid` of course. Just added it as an example - otherwise felogin plugin will throw an error, as it is required setting.

**Render within Fluid**

If you would like to render it inside of Fluid template you could copy `plugin.tx_felogin_pi1` object into another TypoScript object, for example `lib.loginBox`

```
lib.loginBox < plugin.tx_felogin_pi1
lib.loginBox.storagePid = 1
```

And then display in Fluid template using `f:cObject` ViewHelper:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.loginBox" />
```

Here are all settings for felogin. All of them can be set in the same way as `storagePid` in examples above.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/felogin/Configuration/Index.html

Answer (score 2):

you can also do this completely without copying anything, like for example:

```
    page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    page.10 { ...
      variables {
        Login = USER_INT
            Login {
                userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
                controllerActionName = login
                controllerExtensionName = Felogin
                controllerName = Login
                pluginName = Login
                extensionName = Felogin
                vendorName = TYPO3

                view {
                    layoutRootPaths {
                        10 = YourPath/Private/Extensions/felogin/Layouts/
                    }

                    templateRootPaths {
                        10 = YourPath/Private/Extensions/felogin/Templates/
                    }

                    partialRootPaths {
                        10 = YourPath/Private/Extensions/felogin/Partials/
                    }
                }

                settings {
                    storagePid = 2
                    pages = 2
                    showForgotPassword = 0
                    showLogoutFormAfterLogin = 0
                    redirectMode = userLogin,groupLogin
                    redirectFirstMethod = 1
                    redirectPageLogin =
                    redirectPageLoginError = 27
                    redirectPageLogout = 27
                    redirectDisable = 0
                    error_header = Fehler
                    success_header = Success
                    success_message = Login erfolgreich
                    showForgotPassword = 0
                }
            }
      }
    }
```

Im FluidTemplate you can use it like:

```
    <f:format.raw>{Login}</f:format.raw>
```

To show the logged in User Image/Name etc. for example this:

```
lib.feUser = COA_INT
lib.feUser {
    10 = FILES
    10 {
        references {
            table = fe_users
            uid.dataWrap = {TSFE:fe_user|user|uid}
            fieldName = image
        }

        begin = 0
        maxItems = 1

        renderObj = IMAGE
        renderObj {
            wrap = <span class="user-image">|</span>
            file {
                import.data = file:current:uid
                import.listNum = 0
                treatIdAsReference = 1
                height = 40
                width = 40c
            }
            altText.data = file:current:alternative
            titleText.data = file:current:title
            stdWrap {
                typolink {
                    parameter.data = file:current:link
                    extTarget = _top
                    ATagParams = title="{file:current:title}"
                    ATagParams.insertData = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }

    20 = TEXT
    20 {
        # wrap = <span class="user-name">|</span>
        # data = TSFE:fe_user|user|username
        value = <img class="dummy-image" src="YourPath/dummy.png" alt="login" width="40" />
        stdWrap.if.isFalse.cObject < lib.feUser.10
    }
}
```

But be aware of some Issues with custom fluid templates:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/90953