# How to render felogin with typoscript in Typo3 10.4 as content element at a certain spot in the template

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x, felogin

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51160380/17107720) method in typo3 v8.4. Here's my TypoScript:

```
lib.loginBox = plugin.tx_felogin_pi1
lib.loginBox.storagePid = 28
```

and in the Template I used this:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.loginBox" />
```

But now in v10.4 it throws [this](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/exceptions/master/en-us/Exceptions/1540246570.html) error and says "No Content Object definition found at TypoScript object path "lib.loginBox"."
When I change the < to = it just won't load the content element.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin moved to extbase, so it is now

```
lib.loginBox = USER
lib.loginBox {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = Felogin
  pluginName = Login
  
  settings < plugin.tx_felogin_login.settings 
  settings {
    pages = 8
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped! Tweaked a few settings, modified the fluid template of felogin and now it words to my likings! Thanks again!

Comment: Alright, fast forward a few months, currently I'm on 11.5.3. The content element shows up where I want it to, but is there a way to define the templateRootPaths (also partial and layout) for that content element? Usually it would be something like `plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.templateRootPaths.10 = {$plugin.tx_felogin_login.view.templateRootPath}`, but if I have two content elements using this plugin, they'll have the same template. Is there a way for them to have each their own template?

Comment: I have tried `lib.loginBox.templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:path-to-my-folder` or `lib.loginBox.templateRootPath = EXT:path-to-my-folder`, which, according to the [fluid-documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content/main/en-us/Configuration/OverridingFluidTemplates/Index.html) should be working, but that doesn't work in this case apparently.

Comment: Still stuck on this, does anybody know an answer maybe?